# Current SSH connection properties (cipher, auth type, timeout, etc)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh

After a connection is established with SSH, how we can get the current connection properties ?

Is there a way to know what cipher(s) is being used ? Properties of the authentication ? Protocol version, timeouts and so on.

Comment: No, but you can find out more than you ever wanted to know about the connection when the handshake is negotiated, by passing 1 to 3 `-v` arguments to `ssh`.

Comment: Yeah! I Know that, but  I would like to get some info, in the current connection (already established)

Comment: Feel free to ask the OpenSSH guys to implement it.  Perhaps something like `pkill -INFO ssh` make it print status, modeled after `dd`.  They might see a value to it.

Answer (score 1):

you can enable verbose more logging for sshd:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

add line

```
LogLevel   VERBOSE
```

and restart sshd

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

view log entry

```
journalctl -u sshd |tail -100
```